# Ubuntu 18.04: No USB, WLAN, HDMI after upgrading kernel

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, kernel, hdmi

My situation:

I upgraded the firmware of my Lenovo T480 (via Ubuntu's "application store") and everything went fine except that I was running `4.18` kernel before and now it did not boot anymore due to some signature problem (Secure Boot is enabled). No problem, I just selected `4.15` from boot menu and it still worked (why?).

So, I installed the newest `5.0.0`. However, after reboot I noticed that USB didn't work, WLAN didn't work and even the external display didn't work anymore. Then I installed `4.17`. Same problem. It seems that only the default `4.15` now works.

Any ideas what has happened?

There are no errors when installing the other kernels. It's just after reboot I'm lacking USB, WLAN and HDMI. Otherwise the kernels seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the newest HWE stack?
Perhaps

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

helps.

Before executing you should read here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack